# sbt, publishLocal, resolve errors

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy, publishing

I want to push my artifacts to local ivy repository in order to use them as dependencies in other projects.

My artifact's build.scala:

```
name := "jsonApi"
organization := "com.github.kondaurovdev"
version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
```

Run publishLocal task:

```
> publishLocal
[info] Packaging /home/user256/Projects/kondaurov/jsonApi/target/scala-2.11/jsonapi_2.11-0.1-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar ...
[info] Wrote /home/user256/Projects/kondaurov/jsonApi/target/scala-2.11/jsonapi_2.11-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] :: delivering :: com.github.kondaurovdev#jsonapi_2.11;0.1-SNAPSHOT :: 0.1-SNAPSHOT :: integration :: Mon May 16 12:07:08 MSK 2016
[info] Done packaging.
[info]  delivering ivy file to /home/user256/Projects/kondaurov/jsonApi/target/scala-2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml
[info] Main Scala API documentation to /home/user256/Projects/kondaurov/jsonApi/target/scala-2.11/api...
[info] Compiling 51 Scala sources to /home/user256/Projects/kondaurov/jsonApi/target/scala-2.11/classes...
model contains 97 documentable templates
[info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
[info] Packaging /home/user256/Projects/kondaurov/jsonApi/target/scala-2.11/jsonapi_2.11-0.1-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Packaging /home/user256/Projects/kondaurov/jsonApi/target/scala-2.11/jsonapi_2.11-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info]  published jsonapi_2.11 to /home/user256/.ivy2/local/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/0.1-SNAPSHOT/poms/jsonapi_2.11.pom
[info]  published jsonapi_2.11 to /home/user256/.ivy2/local/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/0.1-SNAPSHOT/jars/jsonapi_2.11.jar
[info]  published jsonapi_2.11 to /home/user256/.ivy2/local/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/0.1-SNAPSHOT/srcs/jsonapi_2.11-sources.jar
[info]  published jsonapi_2.11 to /home/user256/.ivy2/local/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/0.1-SNAPSHOT/docs/jsonapi_2.11-javadoc.jar
[info]  published ivy to /home/user256/.ivy2/local/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/0.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
```

It seems like everything is ok, but when i run update task in project that depends on that artifact i get some errors:

```
> update
[info] Updating {file:/home/user256/Projects/apiAdmin/back/}apiAdmin...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.github.kondaurovdev#jsonapi_2.11;0.1-SNAPSHOT: java.text.ParseException: [unknown tag project in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag modelVersion in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag groupId in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag artifactId in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag packaging in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag description in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag version in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag name in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag organization in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag name in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag url in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag licenses in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag license in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag name in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag url in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag distribution in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag scm in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag url in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag connection in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag developers in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag developer in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag id in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag name in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] , unknown tag url in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[warn] ]
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          com.github.kondaurovdev:jsonapi_2.11:0.1-SNAPSHOT (/home/user256/Projects/apiAdmin/back/build.sbt#L7)
[warn]            +- com.github.kondaurovdev:apiadmin_2.11:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.kondaurovdev#jsonapi_2.11;0.1-SNAPSHOT: java.text.ParseException: [unknown tag project in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag modelVersion in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag groupId in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag artifactId in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag packaging in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag description in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag version in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag name in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag organization in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag name in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag url in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag licenses in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag license in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag name in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag url in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag distribution in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag scm in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag url in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag connection in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag developers in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag developer in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag id in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag name in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] , unknown tag url in file:/home/user256/.ivy2/cache/com.github.kondaurovdev/jsonapi_2.11/ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml.original
[error] ]
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed May 16, 2016 12:12:14 PM
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 6):

I removed com.github.kondaurovdev from ~./.ivy2/cache and run update task again:

```
> update
[info] Updating {file:/home/user256/Projects/apiAdmin/back/}apiAdmin...
[info] Resolving com.github.kondaurovdev#jsonapi_2.11;0.1-SNAPSHOT ...
[warn] Choosing local for com.github.kondaurovdev#jsonapi_2.11;0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
```

It seems like it's ok

Answer (score 0):

It's been raised as an issue against sbt. https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1824

As you discovered, you can delete the affected directory from your .ivy cache.